# crystal report working in viewer not working in application for date ranges

Tags: java, mysql, crystal-reports

i have a crystal report working in crystal reports Preview page. The same not working on the application.

we are passing the filter(where) parameters from java application to crystal reports, looks not working when added the Date Range in filter, `in Date (2014,08,01) to Date (2014,11,13)` the report is not working.

The same filters applied in crystal report to test working fine.

Compared the both SQL queries generated looks same.
But the report is empty when runned using application.

Any suggestions for debugging the issue?

Comment: if you paste the sql generated in java into sql, do you get desired values?

Comment: There is the confusion, java to SQL returns zero rows first time, after i run the report sql and then run the Java SQL it returns proper results

Comment: so did you find where the issue is?

Comment: Compared the both SQL queries generated looks same. this my road block.

Comment: check the date format which you are sending is it DB format??

Comment: its Crystal report function in Date (2014,08,01) to Date (2014,11,13)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is issue with filter string passing from java to crystal reports, string length seems have some restrictions.

i reduced filter string which is been passing to CR made issue fixed.